# Custom filter in server driven datagrid submits component instead of expected value

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am creating a handful of custom filters for a server driven datagrid we are building. Up until now we've only used the default string filter which submits the expected format:

> `{ property: string; value: string; }`

The screenshot below shows the console output for this as reference.

[image: screenshot of basic string filter output]

However when I replace the standard filter with a custom filter and I submit a simple string value through the `ClrDatagridFilterInterface` Observable next method, the datagrid state gives me the full custom component (see screenshot below).

[image]

I recreated this here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mr1yhy

Is this the expected behaviour of a custom filter? and if so is there a way to bypass this and just return the `property/value` combination?

PS. I know said interface allows both types (as shown below), I'd just like the first one and I can't seem to find the solution.

```
export interface ClrDatagridStateInterface<T = any> {
    page?: {
        from?: number;
        to?: number;
        size?: number;
    };
    sort?: {
        by: string | ClrDatagridComparatorInterface<T>;
        reverse: boolean;
    };
    filters?: ({
        property: string;
        value: string;
    } | ClrDatagridFilterInterface<T>)[];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a demonstration of your exact filter doing this in a Stackblitz? It helps to see the same thing you are.

Comment: @JeremyWilken Of course, i recreated it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mr1yhy (look at console output after applying filters)

Comment: You're assuming custom filters always have a corresponding property and value, but it's not necessarily the case. They might have an array of values, an object value, they might be tied to 2 or more properties at once, etc.
Maybe Clarity could offer a way for you to specify the format of the filter you want to receive as part of the whole state, but by default custom filters will have to output themselves since we cannot make any assumptions on what they do.

Comment: Yeah, I've created a custom interface now that ensure's these properties are defined. However the `ClrDatagridStateInterface` obviously doesn't use my interface, so I'm still "assuming" that a filter uses this interface, which feels kind of dirty.